# Replaced IDs with Classes and now Javascript won't run

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I've replaced the following **IDs** in my html with **classes**, but I'm having a problem trying to run the javascript. It's supposed to create a play/pause button for a video player.

```
<div class="video_player_box">
    <video class="my_video" width="550" height="300"> 
        <source src="video.mp4"> 
    </video> 
    <div id="video_controls_bar"> 
        <button id="playpausebtn" onclick="playPause(this,'my_video')">
            Pause
        </button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Now please help me make the necessary changes to my javascript so that it runs with classes instead of IDs.

```
function playPause(btn,vid)
{ 
    var vid = document.getElementById(vid); 
    if(vid.paused)
    { 
        vid.play(); 
        btn.innerHTML = "Pause"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        vid.pause(); 
        btn.innerHTML = "Play"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` strangely enough gets elements by ID, so when using classes you have to use one of the many other methods to get an element.

Comment: Can you go into detail? I tried GetElementsbyClassName but that didnt work either.

Comment: yes, you should use something like this instead:
    var video = document.querySelector('.' + vclass)
where vclass is the name of the class. This assumes that you are only interested in the first element of that class on the page. If you have several, you'll need to be more specific in your targeting. This is where IDs are actually useful.

Comment: Can you go into detail about what "didn't work" means?

Comment: Is there a reason you changed the Id to class? Or do you want to play/pause multiple video's at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
<script> 
    function playPause(btn,vid){ 
        var vids = document.getElementsByClassName(vid);
        for(index = 0; index < vids.length; ++index){
            if(vids[index].paused){ 
                vids[index].play(); 
                btn.innerHTML = "Pause"; 
            } else{ 
                vids[index].pause(); 
                btn.innerHTML = "Play"; 
            }
         } 
     } 
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`

Comment: its `getElementsByClassName`, so it returns an array